# How to make a dropdown menu to search in different models in django

Tags: django

I am new to django and I made a search engine , I want to add a dropdown menu in the template where user can choose the model to search in. What to write in the template and what to write in `views.py` is there is any need for forms.py ????

thanks for help

Comment: Have a look at django-haystack. It provides the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions.

1. You can hardcode your models and filter statements on them directly into your Django view. This is ok if queries are not complex and there is not a lot of models.
2. Or you need an abstraction - a search layer over your Django models. There is a lot of different search engines: solr, sphinx, elastic search. In your case this can be for example Sphinx Search with django-sphnix plugin - it can aggregate different data sources and make them available for search.